# Deserializing "old" xml into new class instance

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've had a class which looked like

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string EmployerName;
    public string EmployerSurname;
    public string EmploeeName;
    public string EmploeeSurname;
}
```

I've refactored the code above to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Employer = new PersonInfo();
        Emploee = new PersonInfo();
    }

    public class PersonInfo
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
    }
    public PersonInfo Emploee;
    public PersonInfo Employer;

    [Obsolete]
    public string EmploeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return Emploee.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Emploee.Name = value;
        }
    }
    [Obsolete]
    public string EmploeeSurname
    {
        get
        {
            return Emploee.Surname;
        }
        set
        {
            Emploee.Surname= value;
        }
    }
    [Obsolete]
    public string EmployerName
    {
        get
        {
            return Employer.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Employer.Name = value;
        }
    }
    [Obsolete]
    public string EmployerSurname
    {
        get
        {
            return Employer.Surname;
        }
        set
        {
            Employer.Surname = value;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, that when deserializing XMLs, which were serialized from old class version, I hoped that the new properties would work, and fields of the inner objects would be filled, but they don't.

Any ideas how, besides implementing IXmlSerializable, I could modify the new class to support both new and old versions of XMLs? Or maybe IXmlSerializable is the only way?

Answer (score 5):

Do you only want to support the old ones for *deserialization*? if so, you could have:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string EmploeeName {
    get { return Emploee.Name; }
    set { Emploee.Name = value; }
}
public bool ShouldSerializeEmploeeName() { return false;}
```

The bool method tells `XmlSerializer` never to *write* this, but it will still be *read*. `[Browsable]` tells it not to appear in things like `DataGridView`, and `[EditorBrowsable]` tells it not to appear in intellisense (only applies to code referencing the *dll*, not the *project*, nor code in the *same* project).